# ActiveQt как подключить?

Tags: c++, qt

Пытался подключить разными способами, но все время выдает одну и туже ошибку что не видит ActiveQt/QAxWidget(подключал #include <ActiveQt/QAxWidget>)(ActiveQt/QAxWidget: No such file or directory) или #include (#include )(QAxWidget: No such file or directory).

```
QT       += core gui
#QT       += core gui widgets axcontainer
QT       += core gui widgets activeqt
#QT       += widgets activeqt
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET   = qutlook
QT += widgets axcontainer

TYPELIBS = $$system(dumpcpp -getfile {00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046})

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17
#CONFIG += qaxcontainer

CONFIG += activeqt
CONFIG += axwidget
```

Надо для програмы, которая должна читать ексель файл и переносить данные в мою БД.
Погуглил, ничего не помогло. Может я просто кривой какой-то. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Ваша сборка Qt сконфигурирована без поддержки ActiveQt. Вам необходимо либо пересобрать ручками Qt включив соответствующий модуль, либо надо было при установке тыкать нужную галочку (тут не уверен. инсталлером не ставил)
в qmake проверить наличие модуля довольно просто

```
qtHaveModule(axcontainer){
QT+=axcontainer
}else{
 message(axcontainer not configured!)
}
```

Comment: Понял. Попробую.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо на версии выше 6 какого-то лешего не "подключались" все библиотеки. Помогла установка версии 5.1(нашел какой-то вчера китайский сайт де было сказано что-то про ето и решил попробывать) . Главное не 6. Делла по етому алгоритму
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42867557/how-to-install-qtcharts-on-windows
Повторю еще раз. Я не знаю почему оно работает через одно место на версии выше 6 и выше. Самое важное что оно хотя бы работает и подключается на 5. Если у кого-то будет разумное обьяснение, прошу в студию!